# Cognito Role Based Authentication Not working

Tags: amazon-cognito

So, I am new to Cognito and trying to link it with my Lambda Functions. I am trying to divide my API calls for different IAM roles. Here are the steps which I have already tried but the policy is not applied:

- I created a User Pool and its App Client first, and divided the Pool into three Groups.
- I created a Federated Identity with the User Pool Id and Client Id. For Role Selection I did 
  'Choose role from Token'.
- I created a IAM Role with Identity ID, and attached this policy to it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "execute-api:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- I attached the IAM Role to the User Pool Group 1.
- I created a Cognito Authorizer, and attached it to an API in API Gateway.
- I created a User, and assigned it to Group 1. After logging in, I got an ID_Token whose JWT 
  decryption included the Role I had attached.
- Finally, I made a Request from Postman with the token, and expected the Response to be 
  Forbidden as I had denied everything in the policy.

In the end, the Response I got was 200, and the access was not restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIGateway only checks with cognito if your token is valid or not. If you then use the token to generate temporary AWS credentials and use them to make any requests to AWS resources (including to APIGateway), then you will get the forbidden response for your requests.

Comment: Did you add this authorizer to API call and republish the APIs?

Comment: So, I got that. Now I can use AWS temporary credentials to authorize APIs. But the problem is these credentials expire after 1 hour. What can be a better approach to this? Requesting for these credentials from the Back-end after every 1 hour or using the id_token to fetch them from front-end whenever they expire?

Comment: The best way to use it was how you were doing it before. Just pass the id Token to your backend and convert the token into credentials in the back end itself. In the front end you can keep refreshing the tokens. Most of the front end AWS libraries automatically refresh your tokens when session is called so you don't even need to program the refreshing yourself.

Comment: The backend is a Lambda Function. You mean that I should validate the User Claim inside that function to return the Resource or Not?

Comment: Use the authorizer to check if token is valid and not expired. Once the APIGateway triggers a lambda, convert the token to credentials. You can then use these credentials to do operations from the lambda itself or you can use them to sign presigned urls so your front end is authenticated to do some tasks.